# ionic crash on ios9 when input focus

Tags: ionic-framework, ios9

## Log Info:

This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

Comment: that information is quite straightforward, I guess... so what is your question?

Comment: more details on this issue [ionic issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4402)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with some third party keyboards and iOS 9.

Check this thread here for more information:

[iOS 9 Ionic Cordova App Crashes on iPhone; works on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744781/ios-9-ionic-cordova-app-crashes-on-iphone-works-on-ipad/)